# How would I print specific parts of this json data?

Tags: python, json

I am using an API and I was struggling to understand how I'd print a specific piece of data. Currently, I request the data from the API, it gets sent back, and when I print the data it comes back as seen below. Currently my code looks something like this :
`print (data["data"]["platformInfo"]["platformUserHandle"])`
With this, I get the error : **KeyError: 'data'**

I am basically (to test) trying to output the user's steam name, but I am struggling. Any help is appreciated. If it simple to output just the user handle, will it be similarly easy to output something further down the data, for example "values" of "bombsPlanted" ect? Thanks in advance.

```
{
  "data": {
    "platformInfo": {
      "platformSlug": "steam",
      "platformUserId": "76561198153039097",
      "platformUserHandle": "Anomaly",
      "platformUserIdentifier": "76561198153039097",
      "avatarUrl": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/6e/6e2349c7479c9a952606db2153527a866b78017d_full.jpg",
      "additionalParameters": null
    },
    "userInfo": {
      "userId": null,
      "isPremium": false,
      "isVerified": false,
      "isInfluencer": false,
      "isPartner": false,
      "countryCode": null,
      "customAvatarUrl": null,
      "customHeroUrl": null,
      "socialAccounts": null,
      "pageviews": null,
      "isSuspicious": null
    },
    "metadata": {},
    "segments": [
      {
        "type": "overview",
        "attributes": {},
        "metadata": {
          "name": "Lifetime"
        },
        "expiryDate": "2021-04-07T17:04:09.6917371+00:00",
        "stats": {
          "timePlayed": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 87,
            "displayName": "Time Played",
            "displayCategory": "General",
            "category": "general",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 4636774,
            "displayValue": "53d 15h 59m",
            "displayType": "TimeSeconds"
          },
          "score": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 74,
            "displayName": "Score",
            "displayCategory": "General",
            "category": "general",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 139594,
            "displayValue": "139,594",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "kills": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 80,
            "displayName": "Kills",
            "displayCategory": "Combat",
            "category": "combat",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 56518,
            "displayValue": "56,518",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "deaths": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 83,
            "displayName": "Deaths",
            "displayCategory": "Combat",
            "category": "combat",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 58422,
            "displayValue": "58,422",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "kd": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 31,
            "displayName": "K/D",
            "displayCategory": "Combat",
            "category": "combat",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 0.9674095375029954,
            "displayValue": "0.97",
            "displayType": "NumberPrecision2"
          },
          "damage": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 82,
            "displayName": "Damage",
            "displayCategory": "Combat",
            "category": "combat",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 8550847,
            "displayValue": "8,550,847",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "headshots": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 87,
            "displayName": "Headshots",
            "displayCategory": "Combat",
            "category": "combat",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 28977,
            "displayValue": "28,977",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "dominations": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 58,
            "displayName": "Dominations",
            "displayCategory": "Combat",
            "category": "combat",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 207,
            "displayValue": "207",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "shotsFired": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 75,
            "displayName": "Shots Fired",
            "displayCategory": "Combat",
            "category": "combat",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 806268,
            "displayValue": "806,268",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "shotsHit": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 75,
            "displayName": "Shots Hit",
            "displayCategory": "Combat",
            "category": "combat",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 155010,
            "displayValue": "155,010",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "shotsAccuracy": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 43,
            "displayName": "Shots Accuracy",
            "displayCategory": "Combat",
            "category": "combat",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 19.225617288544257,
            "displayValue": "19.2%",
            "displayType": "NumberPercentage"
          },
          "snipersKilled": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 78,
            "displayName": "Snipers Killed",
            "displayCategory": "Combat",
            "category": "combat",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 3920,
            "displayValue": "3,920",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "dominationOverkills": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 79,
            "displayName": "Domination Overkills",
            "displayCategory": "Combat",
            "category": "combat",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 478,
            "displayValue": "478",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "dominationRevenges": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 36,
            "displayName": "Domination Revenges",
            "displayCategory": "Combat",
            "category": "combat",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 43,
            "displayValue": "43",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "bombsPlanted": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 73,
            "displayName": "Bombs Planted",
            "displayCategory": "Objective",
            "category": "objective",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 1628,
            "displayValue": "1,628",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "bombsDefused": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 81,
            "displayName": "Bombs Defused",
            "displayCategory": "Objective",
            "category": "objective",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 546,
            "displayValue": "546",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "moneyEarned": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 92,
            "displayName": "Money Earned",
            "displayCategory": "Objective",
            "category": "objective",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 192151725,
            "displayValue": "192,151,725",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "hostagesRescued": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 35,
            "displayName": "Hostages Rescued",
            "displayCategory": "Objective",
            "category": "objective",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 4,
            "displayValue": "4",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "mvp": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 81,
            "displayName": "MVP",
            "displayCategory": "Objective",
            "category": "objective",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 6631,
            "displayValue": "6,631",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "wins": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 83,
            "displayName": "Wins",
            "displayCategory": "Round",
            "category": "round",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 1230,
            "displayValue": "1,230",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "ties": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": null,
            "displayName": "Ties",
            "displayCategory": "Round",
            "category": "round",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 0,
            "displayValue": "0",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "matchesPlayed": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 82,
            "displayName": "Matches Played",
            "displayCategory": "Round",
            "category": "round",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 2829,
            "displayValue": "2,829",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "losses": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 82,
            "displayName": "Losses",
            "displayCategory": "Round",
            "category": "round",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 1599,
            "displayValue": "1,599",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "roundsPlayed": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 89,
            "displayName": "Rounds Played",
            "displayCategory": "Round",
            "category": "round",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 66675,
            "displayValue": "66,675",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "roundsWon": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 83,
            "displayName": "Rounds Won",
            "displayCategory": "Round",
            "category": "round",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 1230,
            "displayValue": "1,230",
            "displayType": "Number"
          },
          "wlPercentage": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 60,
            "displayName": "Win %",
            "displayCategory": "Round",
            "category": "round",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 43.5,
            "displayValue": "43.5%",
            "displayType": "NumberPercentage"
          },
          "headshotPct": {
            "rank": null,
            "percentile": 93,
            "displayName": "Headshot %",
            "displayCategory": "Combat",
            "category": "combat",
            "metadata": {},
            "value": 51.3,
            "displayValue": "51.3%",
            "displayType": "NumberPercentage"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "availableSegments": [],
    "expiryDate": "2021-04-07T17:04:09.6917371+00:00"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce and complete this to a [mre].

Comment: Assuming that this dictionary is named `data`, then `data["data"]` should not give that error. "Something like" that might, however.

Comment: i am not sure but i dont see first `{` at start when pasted the above data in string with `{` at start and then loaded with json.loads(string) it worked and i was able to access the json path you provided.

Comment: @JB The `{` is in the post, he just made the common mistake of putting it on the same line as the triple backticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print values further down the data, you may try to do like this:

```
print (data["data"]["segments"][0]["stats"]["bombsPlanted"]["value"])
```

Answer (score 0):

First it looks like a curly bracket is missing on the top.

Using [load from json module](https://pynative.com/python-json-load-and-loads-to-parse-json/) will be helpful in this situation:

What JSON.load does is "translate" json file or  valid json string into python object(dict)

```
import json


data_from_api = request.get(...)

parsed_data = json.load(data_from_api)
```

and now from the dictionary object you are free to print the data as you did:

```
print(parsed_data["data"]["platformInfo"]["platformUserHandle"])
```

If you are not sure if "platformUserHandle" is always defined in your response, and you don't want to get KeyError you should check

```
dict.get(KEY, ValueWhenKeyNotExist)
```

In this case:

```
print(parsed_data['data']["platformInfo"].get("platformUserHandle", None))
```